# Prove that $y-x < \delta$

Tags: inequality, approximation

In Hardy's *Pure Mathematics* it says if $x^2<2$, $ \  \ y^2>2$, $ \ \ 2-x^2 < \delta$ and $y^2 - 2 < \delta$, then $y-x<\delta$. I added the last two inequalities to get $(y+x)(y-x)<2\delta$.

How do I proceed from here?

Comment: Yes, we can assume that, because the book says that $x^2$ is an under-approximation and $y^2$ is an over-approximation.

Comment: Are $x,y,\delta$ all positive?

Comment: That's the problem I'm having. It doesn't say $x$ is positive, but that seems to be necessary!

Comment: It does say, as I said above, that $x^2<2, y^2>2$.

Comment: $x^2$ is an underapproximation of $2$. This problem was about approximating $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Though $10$ wouldn't work because $2-10^2\not<1$.

Comment: You have to assume $x$ is positive.  Otherwise, let $x = -7/5, y = 10/7, \delta = 1/20$.  Then $2-x^2 = 1/25 < \delta, y^2-2 = 2/49 < \delta$, but $y-x = 99/35 \gg \delta$.

Answer (score 0):

With the information given it is easy to show that $0<y^2-x^2<2\delta$, forcing $\delta$ to be positive. Then $$x^2<2+\delta \tag 1$$ and we can also see from $y^2>2$ that $$-y^2<-2\tag 2$$ The sum of $(1)$ and $(2)$ gets us $$x^2-y^2 =(x-y)(x+y)<\delta \tag 3$$ It is also clear from what was given that $x^2-y^2<0$, making exactly one of the quantities $(x-y),(x+y)$ negative and exactly one positive. If $(x-y)$ is positive then $(y-x)$ is negative so trivially $y-x<\delta$. Clearly we need only consider the case that $(x-y)$ is negative. This gets us that $y-x$ and $y+x$ are positive quantities. Can you proceed from here, either by contradiction or directly, to show that $y-x<\delta$? There is more to unpack from what is given that may be useful. For example, $y>0$ when $(y+x),(y-x)$ are both greater than zero.

Comment: I need more help to proceed from $y-x >0$ and $y+x > 0$ to $y-x < \delta$.

Answer (score 0):

This is [exercise 4, p.11](https://archive.org/stream/coursepuremath00hardrich#page/n27/) from Hardy's ["A course of Pure Mathematics"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Course_of_Pure_Mathematics). Some thoughts of the author related to the problem are supplied in a remark by the end of p.8 of the same book.

The exercise's exact statement is:

> *"If $x,y$ are approximations to $\sqrt{2}$, by defect and by excess respectively, and $2-x^2<\delta$, $y^2-2<\delta$, then $y-x<\delta$.* "

If we consider the $x,y$ as values $x_n,y_n$ of some positive sequences,  approximating $\sqrt{2}$ by defect and by excess respectively, and $0<\delta<2$, then the initial inequalities $2-x^2<\delta$, $y^2-2<\delta$ can be solved to give:
$$
\sqrt{2}<y<\sqrt{2+\delta} \ \textrm{   and  } \ \sqrt{2-\delta}<x<\sqrt{2}
$$
Now, if we sum the above we get:
$$
x+y>\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2-\delta}>\sqrt{2-\delta}+\sqrt{2-\delta}=2\sqrt{2-\delta}
$$
and since:
$$
(y+x)(y-x) < 2\delta
$$
we have that:
$$
2\sqrt{2-\delta}(y-x) < 2\delta \Rightarrow  \\ \\ \sqrt{2-\delta}(y-x) < \delta 
$$
Now, confining $0<\delta<1$ we have that $\sqrt{2-\delta}>1$, thus the last inequality produces:
$$
y-x<\sqrt{2-\delta}(y-x)< \delta \Rightarrow \\ \\ \\ 
 y-x< \delta
$$
which is what the exercise asks for.