# Showing that $y^2-2 < \delta$ and $2-x^2 < \delta$ $\implies y-x < \delta$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, inequality, approximation

[image]

This question is from Hardy's book, which I'm working through. This isn't the usual $\epsilon-\delta$ question, where I can try to bound $x$ and $y$. I'm given the conditions for $\ f(x)$ instead, and from those conditions deduce how close $x$ and $y$ must be.

Right off the bat I can think of adding the two inequalities, arriving at

$$y^2-2 + 2-x^2 =y^2-x^2 = (y+x)(y-x) < 2\delta$$

So

$$(y+x)(y-x) < 2\delta$$

This gives a hint of what is needed, but I can't seem to proceed. Perhaps I'm missing something obvious. Another constraint that I know is $ (y+x)(y-x) < 4$, but again, I can't seem to make it work.

Comment: Which of Hardy's books is this question from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my understanding, the exercise implies that both $x,y$, are values of some (positive) sequences which approximate $\sqrt{2}$, in the sense that they tend to limit $\sqrt{2}$ (by defect and by excess respectively). We might right $x_n,y_n$ to emphasize this, but it is not necessary.

Considering $0<\delta<2$, 
$$
2-x^2<\delta \Leftrightarrow x^2-(2-\delta)>0 \Leftrightarrow \big(x-\sqrt{2-\delta}\big)\big(x+\sqrt{2-\delta}\big)>0 \Leftrightarrow \\ \\
x<-\sqrt{2-\delta} \textrm{  or  } x>\sqrt{2-\delta}
$$
Similarly
$$
y^2-2<\delta \Leftrightarrow  y^2-(2+\delta)<0 \Leftrightarrow \\
-\sqrt{2+\delta}<y<\sqrt{2+\delta}
$$
Then, since $x,y$ are both positive and they are approximations to $\sqrt{2}$, by defect and by excess respectively, we have:
$$
\sqrt{2}<y<\sqrt{2+\delta} \ \textrm{   and  } \ \sqrt{2-\delta}<x<\sqrt{2}
$$ 
and thus
$$
x+y>\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2-\delta}>2\sqrt{2-\delta}
$$
Substituting in OP's inequality:
$$ 
(y+x)(y-x) < 2\delta \Rightarrow \\ \\ \\ 2\sqrt{2-\delta}(y-x)<(y+x)(y-x) < 2\delta \Rightarrow \\ \\ \\
2\sqrt{2-\delta}(y-x)< 2\delta \Rightarrow \\ \\ \\ 
\sqrt{2-\delta}(y-x)< \delta
$$
Now, if $0<\delta<1$ (which seems a quite reasonable choice, although not specified in the question), the above gives (since $0<\delta<1\Rightarrow \sqrt{2-\delta}>1$):
$$
y-x<\sqrt{2-\delta}(y-x)< \delta \Rightarrow \\ \\ \\ 
 y-x< \delta
$$

Comment: The book is called "A course of pure mathematics". I just found that another user had asked the same question a year ago (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1327765/prove-that-y-x-delta?rq=1), and the answer given by graydad seems very slick; however, I'm not sure how how the argument would lead to the desired inequality. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowledge, what is approximation in the sense of this book, it is not true.

Example: Ley $\delta=0.1$, $y=\sqrt2$, $x=-100$.

($-100$ may be an approximation of $\sqrt2$, indeed!)

Comment: In the question $y$ must exceed $\sqrt2$, so how can $y=\sqrt 2$? Other than that, thanks --- one can easily find counterexamples, I wonder why Hardy included this question in his book.

Comment: Without information from the book, $y=\sqrt2$ is pretty good. Moreover: exact values is the best approximation. :-) I hope that it is not a book of  G. H. Hardy https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G._H._Hardy

Comment: It is by G.H. Hardy. See the other answer, perhaps that was what Hardy meant.